# Loading Haskell plugins on-the-fly

Tags: haskell, llvm

I need to write a Haskell application which loads another Haskell plugins on-fly. Plugin is an arbitrary source code, once loaded it runs for a quite long time, so it would be beneficial to compile it somehow before it's used. I also think about using LLVM for that.
I assume this is surely an already solved problem. How to do that in a robust way?

Comment: See the 'hint' package on hackage.

Comment: This question is relevant to my interests. I'm never sure exactly which one of the half-dozen dynamic loading packages is the "current" one... (And, in any case, I've never managed to get this to work.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the `plugins` package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins. That's what I've used to get dynamic loading of Haskell code in the past. There's also http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins-auto which is a wrapper around `plugins` so it could be worth taking a look too.

edit:
If you want to go deeper here's a paper describing the plugins package [www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/papers/hs-plugins.ps.gz](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/papers/hs-plugins.ps.gz)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at XMonad. It does this. http://xmonad.org

Comment: Yes, but It would be helpful of you to explain a little more, since as far as I remember, xmonad.org focusses on _using_ the window manager rather than how it does plugins behind the scenes. Just a link is only really helpful if at the end of the link there's a clear answer to this specific question.

Comment: I'd be too interested in knowing how XMonad does that. It seems to me that it compiles modified sources and replaces itself with a new process, but that's just a guess. If anybody knows the details, please add it.